# Any other method instead of using subquery in select list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `document_header` and `document_allocation`:

```
CREATE TABLE document_header 
(
    id int, 
    originalAmount decimal(5, 2), 
    doc_type char(2)
)

INSERT INTO document_header(id, originalAmount, doc_type) 
VALUES (1001, '200.00', 'PV'),
       (1002, '150.00', 'PV'),
       (1003, '300.00', 'IV'),
       (1004, '400.00', 'IV'),
       (1005, '600.00', 'IV')

CREATE TABLE document_allocation 
(
    id int, 
    allocatedto int, 
    allocatedfrom int, 
    allocatedamount decimal(5, 2)
)

INSERT INTO document_allocation 
VALUES (1, 1003, 1001, '100.00'),
       (2, 1004, 1001, '50.00'),
       (3, 1003, 1002, '50.00'),
       (4, 1005, 1001, '50.00'),
       (5, 1004, 1002, '50.00'),
       (6, 1003, 1001, '20.00')
```

I want to get the original document amount also the amount allocated.

Expected result:

| originalDocumentId | documentOriginalAmount | allocatedBy | allocatedamount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1003 | 300.00 | 1001 | 120.00 |
| 1003 | 300.00 | 1002 | 50.00 |
| 1004 | 400.00 | 1001 | 50.00 |
| 1004 | 400.00 | 1002 | 50.00 |
| 1005 | 600.00 | 1001 | 30.00 |

SQL that returns the result as expected

```
SELECT
    originalDocument.id AS OriginalDocumentID,
    document_header.id AS allocatedBy,
    (SELECT SUM(document_header_a.originalAmount) 
     FROM document_header document_header_a 
     WHERE document_header_a.id = originalDocument.id),
    SUM(document_allocation.allocatedamount) AS amountAllocated
FROM
    document_header,
    document_allocation,
    document_header originalDocument
WHERE
    document_header.id = document_allocation.allocatedfrom AND
    originalDocument.id = document_allocation.allocatedto
GROUP BY
    originalDocument.id,
    document_header.id
```

But I don't want to use subquery in the select list, is there any other method?

I tried as below, but it double up the amount

```
SELECT
    originalDocument.id AS OriginalDocumentID,
    document_header.id AS allocatedBy,
    SUM(originalDocument.originalAmount) AS documentOriginalAmount,
    SUM(document_allocation.allocatedamount) AS amountAllocated
FROM
    document_header,
    document_allocation,
    document_header originalDocument
WHERE
    document_header.id = document_allocation.allocatedfrom AND
    originalDocument.id = document_allocation.allocatedto
GROUP BY
    originalDocument.id,
    document_header.id
```

Result of this SQL

| OriginalDocumentID | documentOriginalAmount | allocatedBy | amountAllocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1003 | 600.00 | 1001 | 120.00 |
| 1003 | 300.00 | 1002 | 50.00 |
| 1004 | 400.00 | 1001 | 50.00 |
| 1004 | 400.00 | 1002 | 50.00 |
| 1005 | 600.00 | 1001 | 30.00 |

Is there any other method that I can write my SQL so that I can skip using subquery?

Comment: In SQL, you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. Provided you are asking for the same logical result, the optimizer should produce exactly the same plan no matter how you describe that result, e.g. whether or not you use a subquery. So why do you think you want to avoid the subquery?

Comment: Also, BTW, please stop using comma joins. Explicit join syntax was added to the SQL standard in *1992*, I.e. over a quarter of a century ago. You really should prefer to use it.

Comment: *Why* do you think you need to avoid a sub query? And [Bad habbits](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) you really should have kicked by now.

Comment: Try use ``min(originalDocument.originalAmount) as documentOriginalAmount``

Comment: instead of the sub-query just select `originalDocument.originalAmount` and include it in the `GROUP BY`

Comment: @ValNik ya, it works! But I wonder, why when I use MIN() it gets the amount correctly.

Comment: You can take ``any`` of values ``originalDocument.originalAmount`` - they are the same. Min(),max() ...

Comment: You're seriously overcomplicating your query; https://dbfiddle.uk/ey51hy9a

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
  Select allocatedTo, allocatedFrom, Sum(allocatedamount) amountAllocated
  from document_allocation Group by AllocatedTo, allocatedFrom 
)
Select c.allocatedto as originalDocumentId
  , c.allocatedfrom as allocatedBy
  , H.originalAmount
  , C.amountallocated
from cte as c
inner join document_header H on H.id = c.allocatedto
```

Here is the [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JI6-M3Wq) for you.

Explanation:
With CTE you will not have to use any subquery as CTE can handle that part and is also easy to use in place of subquery.
Join or subquery in from can also be used but it will defeat the purpose.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).